# How do you get a mtgox api key?

Tags: mtgox, api

I can't seem to find where to get my MtGox api key. I've been linked to https://mtgox.com/settings/apps-and-api, but all I get is a blank page in the "Access" section. Do I need to verify my account in order to get API access? Is there any way I can get API access immediately without verifying my account if this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your logged in go to **Security Center** and then you will see a tab which says **Advanced API key Creation** click on that and you will see the permission options, a key name field, and a key generation button.